# Angular 4: How to make dynamic tabs using ng-boostrap api

Tags: angular, tabs, ng-bootstrap

I am attempting to develop a tab view where I could dynamically load tabs during runtime. I recently started using ngb-tabset from the ng-boostrap, and found it very useful except I can't seem to create tabs dynamically.

Long2know has created almost exactly what I've been trying to implement [here.](http://long2know.com/2016/11/exploring-angular2-bootstrap-part-1/)
The challenge currently is providing the data for this example to work. Ideally, if it was possible to create something like this

```
<ngb-tabset  (tabChange)="tabChange($event)" [activeId]="activeId">
    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let comp of components; [id]="start" title="tab1">
        <template ngbTabContent >
            <div> *createTab="comp" </div>
        </template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Where "components" would be an array of different components. Consequently, createTab would be a directive that used factoryResolver with ViewContainerRef to make component on the fly.

If I try something like this I will not get an error, but the tab view will not show at all. After looking at the source code of the [ngb-tabset](http://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabset/tabset.ts) I realized that it uses @ContentChildren to obtain the tab content which doesn't work with creating components dynamically with ViewContainerRef.

I am just wondering if there is some other way that might be similar to achieve this? I know there is probably way to accomplish this with the router, however I've invested a lot more time into this approach so it would be preferred, but I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false">
...
</ngb-tabset>
```

This will prevent the elements to be destroyed